# Load only page content if url contains php parameter

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to load load only the page content (prevent loading header menu or footer) if the url contains `?mode=quick`

I've tried adding the following to the top of my header.php to try only loading the content of the page but it didn't work.

```
<?php
    if ($_GET['mode'] == 'quick'){
        the_content();
        exit();
    }
?>
```

I *was able* to prevent the footer from loading by adding the following code to `page.php` before the last line.

```
<?php
    if ($_GET['mode'] == 'quick'){
        exit();
    }
?>

<?php get_footer(); ?> // Last line
```

Is there a way to do a similar thing but prevent the header from loading as well?

Comment: What does the_content() do?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/

Comment: `if ($_GET['mode'] == 'quick')` should be `if (!empty($_GET['mode']) && $_GET['mode'] == 'quick')`.

Comment: Same result after adding  `!empty($_GET['mode']`

Comment: @spencerlarry Yes, it would give you the same result, but would prevent errors from showing up if `$_GET['mode']` is not set.

Comment: I'm guessing perhaps `the_content()` simply isn't defined / has anything to display while in header.php, and only works in `page.php` due to something that is only included there, or defined after `get_header()` is called, or some such. For example what happens if header.php simply contains only `the_content()` with no conditional?

Comment: problem is get_header() also loads a lot of other things including hooks for js, etc. better to modify the header.php file to control what is displayed when your conditional is true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to create a duplicate of `header.php` and rename it to `header-empty.php`

I modified the code in the new header file to strip it down. Then I had it conditionally load that header if the url parameter was correct.

Wordpress requires the `get_header()` function so I couldn't avoid calling it.

---

Beginning of `page.php`

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_GET['mode']) && $_GET['mode'] == 'quick'){
        get_header('empty');
    } else {
        get_header();
    }
?>
```

End

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['mode']) && $_GET['mode'] == 'quick'){
        exit();
    }
?>
<?php get_footer(); ?> // Last line
```

Answer (score 0):

index page

```
require "pages/".$page.".php";

require_once("layouts/footer.php");
?>
```

header.php

```
          $page = "home";
            if(isset($_GET['page'])){
                if($_GET['page']=='quick'){          
                  $page = $_GET['page'];
                }
            }
```

I hope it will be helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple! :)

```
if(!isset($_GET["quick"])) { loadHeader(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to invert where you put your logic:

```
<?php
    // Only show the header if 'mode' is NOT set or set to something not equal to 'quick'
    if (!isset($_GET['mode'] || $_GET['mode'] != 'quick'){
        get_header();
    }
    the_content();  //This is the one part that is ALWAYS shown
    if (!isset($_GET['mode'] || $_GET['mode'] != 'quick'){
        get_footer();
    }
?>
```